# Extension methods in a class library

Tags: vb.net

I was making a class library with some string and integer functions and I came across extension methods and wanted to build some in my library. After I try to use it in my other project through the library it doesn't recognize it.
Take this example:

```
<HideModuleName>
Public Module StringExtensions

<Extension()>
Public Sub Print(ByVal aString As String)
    Console.WriteLine(aString)
End Sub


End Module
```

This sub takes a string and writes it(just an example) but I cannot use it in another project by reference. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: include the module in the other project(s)

Comment: In addition to @Plutonix's comment you can choose to link it to your other projects, meaning once you change the original file it will be changed in all your projects.